# navigator.getUsermedia for safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, webrtc

I want to get mic Access in safari, and want to control user permission popup event, so that user doesn't ignore the popup by mistake, what is the alternative for navigator.getUsermeda in safari?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only option right now appears to be flash